# Remove Git Repo From 1 Folder and Add that Folder to Another Repo Git

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project which has it's own git repo, this one I would like to keep. However I used a library that I cloned from github. I cloned this into a subfolder of my project. So the folder structure is correct.

What would be the best way to remove the repo from the library and add the library to my own repo? I need to keep the history in my project but not in the library.

**EDIT**

I use Tower to manage git this shows the follow. I guess it being in a submodule is the problem. How to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the .git folder that came with the library. This will loose all the history of the library from GitHub, but that seems to be what you want.

Assuming linux/osx:

```
cd /path/to/library/dir
rm -rf .git/
```

Once you have removed the GitHub repo, you can add it with just a normal git add:

```
cd /path/to/library/dir
git add .
```

Comment: I trued this but I am unable to add. There is no error but it does not go to staging

Comment: I have not used Tower, but the screenshot makes me thing the .git folder from the GitHub library is still there. Have you tried deleting it with the terminal?

Comment: I deleted the whole directory and cloned it again with gitsubmodule. i think that solved it

Comment: Good, glad to hear it! If you can document it more in an answer, I am sure that would be much appreciated!